# TeamCity runs all steps twice

Tags: teamcity

This phenomenon started couple of days go, all of the steps run twice.
First, I though it is just a some log inconsistency, but then I realized that it is also push packages twice (and fails)

any idea what is going on?

(running TeamCity Professional 2017.2.4 (build 51228))

[image]

Comment: Did you recently upgrade TeamCity?  What changed in the last week?

Comment: hmm. yes. we have tried to upgrade last week to 2018.1, it gave up an error that C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\config\main-config.xml got corrupted, (restoring this file from old version didn't help), so we have rolled back TC to the previous version (2017.2.4 = which we are running now) and restored db.  so in theory we should be back to pre-upgrade stage. 
this was the only major change we have done.

Comment: Looks like similar problem in here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-48939 Could you show us whole log?

Comment: I feel uncomfortable posting the log for everyone to see, but let see if send you the log directly...

Comment: looks like i can't send direct messages to users...

Comment: You cannot private message on SO.  Just redact parts of the log you don't want others to see.

Answer (score 1):

ah, figured it out.
we were starting two agents on the same machine:
one as a service and the other as a java command line thing that starts when user logs in.
before services was set to disable but somehow it got enabled...